# Is my code ineffecient or needing the garbage collector?

Tags: libgdx

don't know if you're allowed to ask that here, but I wanted to know if my code is inefficient and leaves much work to the garbage collector, because I'm trying to find a source of lag in my game.

Heres the class, which loads the world through json files.

Worldloader.java:

```
package com.Sidescroll.game.Helpers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Background;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Platform;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Player;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameWorld.GameWorld;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonValue;

public final class WorldLoader {

    private WorldLoader() {}

    public static HashMap<String, GameWorld> worlds = new HashMap<String, GameWorld>();

    private static JsonValue jsonPlatforms, jsonSpawn, jsonBackgrounds;

    public static GameWorld loadWorld(String levelName) {
        if(worlds.get(levelName) != null) return worlds.get(levelName);

        //load json file
        FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("levels/" + levelName + ".json");
        String fileContent = handle.readString();
        JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(fileContent);

        jsonPlatforms = json.get("platforms");
        jsonBackgrounds = json.get("backgrounds");
        jsonSpawn = json.get("spawn");

        //loads platforms
        List<Platform> platforms = new ArrayList<Platform>();
        for(JsonValue pValue : jsonPlatforms.iterator()) {
            Platform platform = new Platform(pValue.getInt("x"),
                                        pValue.getInt("y"),
                                        pValue.getInt("width"),
                                        pValue.getInt("height"),
                                        Platform.Type.valueOf(Platform.Type.class, pValue.getString("type")),
                                        pValue.getString("variant"));
            platforms.add(platform);
        }

        //create player
        Vector2 vecSpawn = new Vector2(jsonSpawn.getInt("x"), jsonSpawn.getInt("y"));
        Player player = new Player(vecSpawn, platforms);

        //loads backgrounds
        List<Background> backgrounds = new ArrayList<Background>();
        for(JsonValue bgValue : jsonBackgrounds.iterator()) {
            Background bg = new Background("bin/sprites/" + bgValue.getString("name") + ".png",
                                            bgValue.getInt("x"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("y"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("width"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("height"),
                                            bgValue.getBoolean("front"));
            backgrounds.add(bg);
        }

        worlds.put(levelName, new GameWorld(player, platforms, backgrounds));
        return worlds.get(levelName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you should never load something "while running"
 if you use a single thread model. So if you do this while "gameplay" it is a bad idea. Ressource loading always takes time and can cause lags.

Comment: @BennX yea, I use it while loading, that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: If the GC is causing lag, you won't find the issue in your loading code. It would be somewhere in your render loop.

Comment: @BennX well, the lag only happens in the first ~5-10 seconds after loading the game and after that it runs smoothly, im not doing anything in the beginning of the game, which is different from the rest, hm

Comment: Try setting your locals to final. Causes a better optimization. Else meight think about calling th gc after loading so it does not happen in gametime. But take care it is bad practice. Maybe it's your render loop or logic.